# Scala: removing a list element by value

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I have recently started learning functional programming on a SCALA. I'm looking for help with with creating of function that take a list with 0 as argument (in the below case lst) and returns new list without 0s (newlst). Currently I created something like below Demo but it doesn't compile due to mismatch exception, any ideas how it can be fixed ? Thanks !

```
object Demo{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val lst = List(0, 1, 2, 0, 3);
    def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      val newlst = list.filter(_ > 0)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the compile error say? You need to return a `List[Int]` from `deletingZeros`, you probably wanted to return `newlst`.

Comment: you just forgot about returning value in `deletingZeros` now it returns `Unit` but according to your signature it should return `List[Int]`, try to remove `val newlst = ` it should helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simple error, you did not return the value from the function. So do one of:

```
def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val newlst = list.filter(_ > 0)

  newlst
}
```

or just

```
def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  list.filter(_ > 0)
}
```

or even just

```
def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  list.filter(_ > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Scala :)

### TL/DR

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
object Demo{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val lst = List(0, 1, 2, 0, 3);
    def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] =
      list.filter(_ > 0)
    val newlst = deletingZeros( lst )
    }
  }
}
```

### Breakdown

The return type of a function must match the type of its last statement. The inner function `deletingZeros` should return a `List` of `Int`, however the assignment-expression `val newlst = ...` is of type `Unit`. That does not match. There are two ways to remedy this. We could return the assigned variable, like so:

```
   def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      val newlst = list.filter(_ > 0)
      newlst
    }
```

since the type of the variable is the type of its value. Or, since we don't use the variable newlst, we could remove it, yielding:

```
    def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      list.filter(_ > 0)
    }
```

which we can in turn simplify to

```
  def deletingZeros(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = list.filter(_ > 0)
```

we can then call this function with `lst` as its argument and assign the result of this call to `newlst`, resulting in the complete example above.